# Is there a way to use <article> css to create a line break?

Tags: css, wordpress, styles

I am trying to edit a WordPress theme's (Spun) CSS and I was wondering if specific posts could be on a separate lines.

I have tried adding `display:block;` but it did not work.
Any thoughts?

Note : I am using the latest chrome browser.

Comment: show a page with the real markup and the css: are you sure you're applying that rule to the right selector? Are you maybe using IE9 or older without `htm5shiv`?

Comment: No ways that `display: block;` wont work for you

Comment: display: block !important;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just experimented a little with the live editing the [preview](http://wordpress.org/themes/spun), add a `float:none` to the `article` you want on a seperate line.

The display attribute seems to be correct, it is the `float:left` which is causing the article elements to stay on the same line.